# pythonにおけるopen関数のencoding引数について

Tags: python, テキストファイル, python2, encoding

以下のようなコードを書いてデータのファイルへの書き込みを試みたのですが、以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます...。
どのように下のコードを修正すれば、簡潔にtextデータをファイルに書き込めますでしょうか...?教えていただけると助かります。(ちなみに自分が使っているpythonはpython2でした...。)

コード

```
   with open(text_file, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as fp:#エラーが発生してしまう場所
                    fp.write(text)
```

エラー

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ExtractText.py", line 36, in <module>
    with open(text_file, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as fp:
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

ちなみにencoding引数を消すと以下のようなエラーになります... 。

コード

```
with open(text_file, 'w') as fp:#エラーが発生してしまう場所
                fp.write(text)
```

エラー

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ExtractText.py", line 37, in <module>
    fp.write(text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: `import io` としてから、`with io.open(text_file, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as fp: fp.write(text.decode("utf-8"))` とするとどうなりますか？

Comment: @metropolis 以下のようになります...。Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ExtractText.py", line 38, in <module>
    fp.write(text.decode("utf-8"))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-10: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: スクリプトファイル自体のエンコーディングが UTF-8 以外になっているのでしょうか？

Comment: python3の方がエンコーディング周りはすっきりしているのですが、python2でなければならない理由があるのでしょうか？

Comment: @metropolis # coding: utf-8 をプログラムの行頭には既に書いていますが、そのことでよろしいでしょうか...?

Comment: @PicoSushi 特に特別な理由は無いので、python3をインストールしようと思います...。

Comment: @firebird 質問の際は他の人が再現可能なようにコードのすべてを質問文に含めてください。 -https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @cubick♦ 今回の場合幾つかのcsvファイルを持っていないとコードの全てを実行することはプログラムの構造上できないのですが、そういった場合はどうすれば良いのでしょうか...?

Comment: python3 で試してみて何か問題が発生したら別質問を立てるなどすればよろしいかと。

Comment: @metropolis 了解です。

Comment: python2の組み込み`open`に`encoding`引数は無いようですが、どの`open`関数を呼んでいるのですか？　https://docs.python.org/ja/2.7/library/functions.html#open

Comment: コードの断片だけ抜き出して書かれると、ヘッダ部分でのライブラリやモジュール呼び出しの定義(import文)が正しく記述されているか等を第三者が判断できません。「`# coding: utf-8 をプログラムの行頭には既に書いている`」とコメントされていますが、これも質問文には含まれていないので読み取りようがありませんよね？ / 質問内容にもよりますが、入力ファイルがあるなら最小限のサンプル(数行程度)を一緒に提示してもらった方がより親切かと思います。

Comment: @cubick♦ 了解しました。次回からできる限りコードを載せようと思います。

Comment: @user10685 python3の関数を呼んでしまっている可能性があるので、python3をインストールしてプログラムを実行し直そうと思います...。

Answer (score 1):

読み込み時ではなく、書き込み時の

```
fp.write(text)
```

でエラーが発生しているのではないでしょうか。

```
for.write(text.encode("utf-8"))
```

とできませんか？

Comment: なるほど...。今度python2に切り替えた時に試してみます。今の所python3で　https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51563/zipfileの解凍において例外が発生した場合に-処理を飛ばす方法  のようにしたら解決しました。

Answer (score -1):

プラットフォームのエンコーディングが違うのかな。
encoding="shift_jis"とかにしてみたらできるかもしれません。

Comment: アドバイスの通りやってみましたが、同じエラーが発生しました...(泣)

Comment: with openの方はencoding='utf-8'の状態で、import sysとして、sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')というコードを追加してみたらどうなりますか？

Comment: 以下のようになりました。Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ExtractText.py", line 8, in <module>
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'