# あるcsvファイルにある文字列のヘッダーを読み込み、別のcsvファイルのヘッダーとして書き込む方法。

Tags: python, python3, csv

以前の質問([https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51521/pythonにおけるopen関数のencoding引数について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51521/python%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8Bopen%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AEencoding%E5%BC%95%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)) において、Python2 を使っていたことで発生していた問題を Python3 をインストールすることで解決をしようと試みたのですが、別の問題が発生してしまいました。
それは、以下のコードで serval_process.csv のヘッダーを pointer.csv のヘッダーとして書き写そうとすると以下のようなエラーが出てしまうことです。
どうすればエラーを出さずに処理を実行できますでしょうか?
教えて頂けると助かります。

コード

```
# coding: utf-8
import csv
import zipfile
import re
#import io
#import sys

root_dir = '/Users/hoge'

with open('serval_process.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    #pointer.csvという新しいcsvファイルを以下で作る。
    g = open('pointer.csv', 'ab') #閉じるのを忘れずに...!
    csvWriter = csv.writer(g)
    
    header = next(reader)  # ヘッダーを読み飛ばしたい時
    csvWriter.writerow(header) #エラーが出る...。
    
    for row in reader:# serval_process.csvのデータを1行づつ取得できる
        local = row[2]#localでzipファイルのある場所
        with zipfile.ZipFile(local, 'r') as zf: #zipファイルを読む
            files = [info.filename for info in zf.infolist() if info.filename.endswith('.txt')]
            for f in files:
                listData = [] #listの初期化
                listData.append(row[0])
                listData.append(row[1])
                bindata = zf.read(f)
                text = bindata.decode(row[3])#この後テキストデータを整形した上でTextに保存したい。
                #テキストの先頭にあるヘッダとフッタを削除
                text = re.split(r'\-{5,}',text)[2]
                text = re.split(r'底本：', text)[0]
                #空白文字、改行およびタブの除去
                text = text.strip()
                #上で加工した書き込むテキストを開く。また、テキストの場所をpointer.csvに記録する。
                text_file = root_dir + '/Text/'+ f
                listData.append(text_file)
                with open(text_file, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as fp:#エラーが発生してしまう場所
                    fp.write(text)
                listData.append('utf-8')
                csvWriter.writerow(listData) #1行書き込み
    g.close()
```

エラー

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ExtractText.py", line 18, in <module>
    csvWriter.writerow(header) #エラーが出る...。
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

出力先のファイルをバイナリモードで開いているのが原因ではないでしょうか。

```
g = open('pointer.csv', 'ab')
```

出力するのが文字列なら以下を試してください。

```
g = open('pointer.csv', 'a')
```

参考: 英語版SOでの類似質問(とその回答)より
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33054552/2322778

Comment: 返信ありがとう御座います...!上のエラーは解決しました。また別のエラーが出てきましたが...。

Comment: 私は普段Pythonを使いませんが、(他の言語の知識も交えながら)エラーメッセージでweb検索することで回答に含めたSOの投稿にたどり着きました。/ 「エラーが出た」から質問するのではなく、まず自分でも調べてみることが大切だと思います。(質問そのものを否定するわけではありません、念のため)

Answer (score 1):

`open('pointer.csv', 'ab')`を`open('pointer.csv', 'a')`に書き換えてください。(第2引数から`b`を削る)

`open('pointer.csv', 'ab')`で[ファイルを開く](https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)と、`a`追記(append)モード＋バイナリモードでファイルを開きます。
このモードで文字列型の`header`を書き込むと、「文字列ではなく、バイト型のオブジェクトが要求されています(意訳)」というエラーになります。

> a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

※エラーメッセージを載せていただいたので、原因が特定しやすくなりました。

Comment: 了解です!返信ありがとう御座います...!